# Chrome memory issue - File API + AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, azure, fileapi

I have a web app that needs to upload large files to Azure BLOB storage. My solution uses HTML5 File API to slice into chunks which are then put as blob blocks, the IDs of the blocks are stored in an array and then the blocks are committed as a blob.

The solution works fine in IE. On 64 bit Chrome I have successfully uploaded 4Gb files but see very heavy memory usage (2Gb+). On 32 bit Chrome the specific chrome process will get to around 500-550Mb and then crash.

I can't see any obvious memory leaks or things I can change to help garbage collection. I store the block IDs in an array so obviously there will be some memory creeep but this shouldn't be massive. It's almost as if the File API is holding the whole file it slices into memory.

It's written as an Angular service called from a controller, I think just the service code is pertinent:

```
(function() {
    'use strict';

    angular
    .module('app.core')
    .factory('blobUploadService',
    [
        '$http', 'stringUtilities',
        blobUploadService
    ]);

function blobUploadService($http, stringUtilities) {

    var defaultBlockSize = 1024 * 1024; // Default to 1024KB
    var stopWatch = {};
    var state = {};

    var initializeState = function(config) {
        var blockSize = defaultBlockSize;
        if (config.blockSize) blockSize = config.blockSize;

        var maxBlockSize = blockSize;
        var numberOfBlocks = 1;

        var file = config.file;

        var fileSize = file.size;
        if (fileSize < blockSize) {
            maxBlockSize = fileSize;
        }

        if (fileSize % maxBlockSize === 0) {
            numberOfBlocks = fileSize / maxBlockSize;
        } else {
            numberOfBlocks = parseInt(fileSize / maxBlockSize, 10) + 1;
        }

        return {
            maxBlockSize: maxBlockSize,
            numberOfBlocks: numberOfBlocks,
            totalBytesRemaining: fileSize,
            currentFilePointer: 0,
            blockIds: new Array(),
            blockIdPrefix: 'block-',
            bytesUploaded: 0,
            submitUri: null,
            file: file,
            baseUrl: config.baseUrl,
            sasToken: config.sasToken,
            fileUrl: config.baseUrl + config.sasToken,
            progress: config.progress,
            complete: config.complete,
            error: config.error,
            cancelled: false
        };
    };

    /* config: {
      baseUrl: // baseUrl for blob file uri (i.e. http://<accountName>.blob.core.windows.net/<container>/<blobname>),
      sasToken: // Shared access signature querystring key/value prefixed with ?,
      file: // File object using the HTML5 File API,
      progress: // progress callback function,
      complete: // complete callback function,
      error: // error callback function,
      blockSize: // Use this to override the defaultBlockSize
    } */
    var upload = function(config) {
        state = initializeState(config);

        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onloadend = function(evt) {
            if (evt.target.readyState === FileReader.DONE && !state.cancelled) { // DONE === 2
                var uri = state.fileUrl + '&comp=block&blockid=' + state.blockIds[state.blockIds.length - 1];
                var requestData = new Uint8Array(evt.target.result);

                $http.put(uri,
                        requestData,
                        {
                            headers: {
                                'x-ms-blob-type': 'BlockBlob',
                                'Content-Type': state.file.type
                            },
                            transformRequest: []
                        })
                    .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                        state.bytesUploaded += requestData.length;

                        var percentComplete = ((parseFloat(state.bytesUploaded) / parseFloat(state.file.size)) * 100
                        ).toFixed(2);
                        if (state.progress) state.progress(percentComplete, data, status, headers, config);

                        uploadFileInBlocks(reader, state);
                    })
                    .error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                        if (state.error) state.error(data, status, headers, config);
                    });
            }
        };

        uploadFileInBlocks(reader, state);

        return {
            cancel: function() {
                state.cancelled = true;
            }
        };
    };

    function cancel() {
        stopWatch = {};
        state.cancelled = true;
        return true;
    }

    function startStopWatch(handle) {
        if (stopWatch[handle] === undefined) {
            stopWatch[handle] = {};
            stopWatch[handle].start = Date.now();
        }
    }

    function stopStopWatch(handle) {
        stopWatch[handle].stop = Date.now();
        var duration = stopWatch[handle].stop - stopWatch[handle].start;
        delete stopWatch[handle];
        return duration;
    }

    var commitBlockList = function(state) {
        var uri = state.fileUrl + '&comp=blocklist';

        var requestBody = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><BlockList>';
        for (var i = 0; i < state.blockIds.length; i++) {
            requestBody += '<Latest>' + state.blockIds[i] + '</Latest>';
        }
        requestBody += '</BlockList>';

        $http.put(uri,
                requestBody,
                {
                    headers: {
                        'x-ms-blob-content-type': state.file.type
                    }
                })
            .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                if (state.complete) state.complete(data, status, headers, config);
            })
            .error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                if (state.error) state.error(data, status, headers, config);
                // called asynchronously if an error occurs
                // or server returns response with an error status.
            });
    };

    var uploadFileInBlocks = function(reader, state) {
        if (!state.cancelled) {
            if (state.totalBytesRemaining > 0) {

                var fileContent = state.file.slice(state.currentFilePointer,
                    state.currentFilePointer + state.maxBlockSize);
                var blockId = state.blockIdPrefix + stringUtilities.pad(state.blockIds.length, 6);

                state.blockIds.push(btoa(blockId));
                reader.readAsArrayBuffer(fileContent);

                state.currentFilePointer += state.maxBlockSize;
                state.totalBytesRemaining -= state.maxBlockSize;
                if (state.totalBytesRemaining < state.maxBlockSize) {
                    state.maxBlockSize = state.totalBytesRemaining;
                }
            } else {
                commitBlockList(state);
            }
        }
    };

    return {
        upload: upload,
        cancel: cancel,
        startStopWatch: startStopWatch,
        stopStopWatch: stopStopWatch
    };
};
})();
```

Are there any ways I can move the scope of objects to help with Chrome GC? I have seen other people mentioning similar issues but understood Chromium had resolved some.

I should say my solution is heavily based on Gaurav Mantri's blog post here:

http://gauravmantri.com/2013/02/16/uploading-large-files-in-windows-azure-blob-storage-using-shared-access-signature-html-and-javascript/#comment-47480

Comment: What is purpose of `var fileContent = state.file.slice`?

Comment: This is the file slice function - I slice the file into chunks so that I upload each chunk and create a blob block.

See:

https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/#toc-slicing-files

Comment: `.slice()` creates a new `Blob` which remains in memory for the life of the `document`, unless the `Blob` is `closed`.

Comment: if a 4gb file was indeed held in RAM, why would it only use 2GB? you might try a short setTimeout around `uploadFileInBlocks(reader, state);` to let GC do it's thing while "not busy"

Answer (score 4):

> I can't see any obvious memory leaks or things I can change to help
>   garbage collection. I store the block IDs in an array so obviously
>   there will be some memory creeep but this shouldn't be massive. It's
>   almost as if the File API is holding the whole file it slices into
>   memory.

You are correct. The new `Blob`s created by `.slice()` are being held in memory.

The solution is to call `Blob.prototype.close()` on the `Blob` reference when processing `Blob` or `File` object is complete.

Note also, at `javascript` at Question also creates a new instance of `FileReader` if `upload` function is called more than once.

> [4.3.1. The slice method](https://w3c.github.io/FileAPI/#slice-method-algo)
>
> The `slice()` method returns a new `Blob` object with bytes ranging
>   from the optional `start` parameter up to but not including the
>   optional `end` parameter, and with a `type` attribute that is the
>   value of the optional `contentType` parameter.

`Blob` instances exist for the life of `document`. Though `Blob` should be garbage collected once removed from `Blob URL Store`

> [9.6. Lifetime of Blob URLs](https://w3c.github.io/FileAPI/#lifeTime)
>
> Note: User agents are free to garbage collect resources removed from
>   the [`Blob URL Store`](https://w3c.github.io/FileAPI/#BlobURLStore).

> Each `Blob` must have an internal ***[snapshot state](https://w3c.github.io/FileAPI/#snapshot-state)***, which must be
>   initially set to the state of the underlying storage, if any such
>   underlying storage exists, and must be preserved through
>   [`StructuredClone`](https://w3c.github.io/FileAPI/#removeTheEntry). Further normative definition of snapshot state can
>   be found for `File`s.

> [4.3.2. The close method](https://w3c.github.io/FileAPI/#close-method)
>
> The `close()` method is said to [`close`](https://w3c.github.io/FileAPI/#closed) a `Blob`, and must act as
>   follows:
>
> 1. If the [`readability state`](https://w3c.github.io/FileAPI/#readabilityState) of the context object is [`CLOSED`](https://w3c.github.io/FileAPI/#dfn-closedState), terminate this algorithm.
> 2. Otherwise, set the `readability state` of the `context object` to `CLOSED`.
> 3. If the context object has an entry in the [`Blob URL Store`](https://w3c.github.io/FileAPI/#BlobURLStore), remove the entry that corresponds to the `context object`.

If `Blob` object is passed to `URL.createObjectURL()`, call `URL.revokeObjectURL()` on `Blob` or `File` object, then call `.close()`.

> The [`revokeObjectURL(url)`](https://w3c.github.io/FileAPI/#dfn-revokeObjectURL) static method
>
> > Revokes the [`Blob URL`](https://w3c.github.io/FileAPI/#blob-url) provided in the string `url` by removing the corresponding entry from the Blob URL Store. This method must act
> >     as follows:
> >     1.  If the [`url`](https://w3c.github.io/FileAPI/#dfn-urlarg) refers to a `Blob` that has a `readability state` of `CLOSED` OR if the value provided for the `url` argument is
> >     not a `Blob URL`, OR if the value provided for the `url` argument does
> >     not have an entry in the `Blob URL Store`, this method call does
> >     nothing. User agents may display a message on the error console.
> >     2.  Otherwise, user agents must [`remove the entry`](https://w3c.github.io/FileAPI/#removeTheEntry) from the `Blob URL Store` for `url`.

You can view the result of these calls by opening

```
chrome://blob-internals
```

reviewing details of before and after calls which create `Blob` and close `Blob`.

For example, from

```
xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx
Refcount: 1
Content Type: text/plain
Type: data
Length: 3
```

to

```
xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx
Refcount: 1
Content Type: text/plain
```

following call to `.close()`. Similarly from

```
blob:http://example.com/c2823f75-de26-46f9-a4e5-95f57b8230bd
Uuid: 29e430a6-f093-40c2-bc70-2b6838a713bc
```

---

An alternative approach could be to send file as an `ArrayBuffer` or chunks of array buffers. Then re-assemble the file at server.

Or you can call `FileReader` constructor, `FileReader.prototype.readAsArrayBuffer()`, and `load` event of `FileReader` each once.

At `load` event of `FileReader` pass `ArrayBuffer` to `Uint8Array`, use `ReadableStream`, `TypedArray.prototype.subarray()`, `.getReader()`, `.read()` to get `N` chunks of `ArrayBuffer` as a `TypedArray` at `pull` from `Uint8Array`. When `N` chunks equaling `.byteLength` of `ArrayBuffer` have been processed, pass array of `Uint8Array`s to `Blob` constructor to recombine file parts into single file at browser; then send  `Blob` to server.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
  <input id="file" type="file">
  <br>
  <progress value="0"></progress>
  <br>
  <output for="file"><img alt="preview"></output>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    const [input, output, img, progress, fr, handleError, CHUNK] = [
      document.querySelector("input[type='file']")
      , document.querySelector("output[for='file']")
      , document.querySelector("output img")
      , document.querySelector("progress")
      , new FileReader
      , (err) => console.log(err)
      , 1024 * 1024
    ];

    progress.addEventListener("progress", e => {
      progress.value = e.detail.value;
      e.detail.promise();
    });

    let [chunks, NEXT, CURR, url, blob] = [Array(), 0, 0];

    input.onchange = () => {
      NEXT = CURR = progress.value = progress.max = chunks.length = 0;
      if (url) {
        URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
        if (blob.hasOwnProperty("close")) {
          blob.close();
        }
      }

      if (input.files.length) {
        console.log(input.files[0]);
        progress.max = input.files[0].size;
        progress.step = progress.max / CHUNK;
        fr.readAsArrayBuffer(input.files[0]);
      }

    }

    fr.onload = () => {
      const VIEW = new Uint8Array(fr.result);
      const LEN = VIEW.byteLength;
      const {type, name:filename} = input.files[0];
      const stream = new ReadableStream({
          pull(controller) {
            if (NEXT < LEN) {
              controller
              .enqueue(VIEW.subarray(NEXT, !NEXT ? CHUNK : CHUNK + NEXT));
               NEXT += CHUNK;
            } else {
              controller.close();
            }
          },
          cancel(reason) {
            console.log(reason);
            throw new Error(reason);
          }
      });

      const [reader, processData] = [
        stream.getReader()
        , ({value, done}) => {
            if (done) {
              return reader.closed.then(() => chunks);
            }
            chunks.push(value);
            return new Promise(resolve => {
              progress.dispatchEvent(
                new CustomEvent("progress", {
                  detail:{
                    value:CURR += value.byteLength,
                    promise:resolve
                  }
                })
              );                
            })
            .then(() => reader.read().then(data => processData(data)))
            .catch(e => reader.cancel(e))
        }
      ];

      reader.read()
      .then(data => processData(data))
      .then(data => {
        blob = new Blob(data, {type});
        console.log("complete", data, blob);
        if (/image/.test(type)) {
          url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
          img.onload = () => {
            img.title = filename;
            input.value = "";
          }
          img.src = url;
        } else {
          input.value = "";
        }             
      })
      .catch(e => handleError(e))

    }
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

plnkr http://plnkr.co/edit/AEZ7iQce4QaJOKut71jk?p=preview

---

You can also use utilize `fetch()`

```
fetch(new Request("/path/to/server/", {method:"PUT", body:blob}))
```

> To **[transmit body](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#concept-request-transmit-body)** for a [request](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#concept-request) *request*, run these
>   steps:
>
> 1. Let *body* be request’s [body](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#concept-request-body).
> 2. If *body* is null, then queue a fetch task on *request* to process request end-of-body for *request* and abort these steps.
> 3. Let *read* be the result of reading a chunk from *body’s* stream.
>
>    - When *read* is fulfilled with an object whose `done` property is false and whose `value` property is a `Uint8Array` object, run these
>        substeps:
>
>      1. Let *bytes* be the byte sequence represented by the `Uint8Array` object.
>      2. Transmit *bytes*.
>      3. Increase *body’s* transmitted bytes by *bytes’s* length.
>      4. Run the above step again.
>    - When *read* is fulfilled with an object whose `done` property is true, queue a fetch task on *request* to process request end-of-body
>        for *request*.
>    - When *read* is fulfilled with a value that matches with neither of the above patterns, or *read* is rejected, terminate the ongoing
>        fetch with reason *fatal*.

See also

- [Progress indicators for fetch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35711724/progress-indicators-for-fetch/)
- [Fetch with ReadableStream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40939857/fetch-with-readablestream)

Comment: Thank you for that, I had not spotted that in the documents. However I am having trouble getting this to work, I changed my uploadFileInBlocks function to be:

var fileContent = state.file.slice(state.currentFilePointer,
    state.currentFilePointer + state.maxBlockSize);
var blockId = state.blockIdPrefix +     stringUtilities.pad(state.blockIds.length, 6);

state.blockIds.push(btoa(blockId));
reader.readAsArrayBuffer(fileContent);
fileContent.prototype.close();

but got errors:

TypeError: Cannot read property 'close' of undefined
    at uploadFileInBlocks

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Blob#Browser_compatibility

Seems it's not supported by any browsers?

Comment: Apparently not. Tried approach at Answer at chromium. Are multiple `POST` requests being made to server?

Comment: If multiple `POST` requests are being made to server, you can alternatively use `FileReader.readAsArrayBuffer`, `Uint8Array`, `ReadableStream` to send chunks of file to server.

Comment: OP is not using BlobURLs, so i don't see what all the talk about their lifetime is about...

Comment: @dandavis _"OP is not using BlobURLs, so i don't see what all the talk about their lifetime is about"_ Not sure what you mean by "all the talk"? _"If Blob object is passed to URL.createObjectURL()"_ Note "If". Have not tried `angularjs`, not entirely certain about everything occurring at `javascript` at Question, though appears `.slice()` is called multiple times which creates a new `Blob`, possibly `.readAsArrayBuffer(fileContent)` as well. The emphasis is `Blob` lifetime, not `Blob URL`; included mention of `Blob URL` for completeness. That portion of Answer can be ignored if not applicable.

Comment: @dandavis Not sure what you mean? `chrome://blob-internals`, at chromium, chrome lists  `Blob`s at `document` which are not closed. What is "vaporware"? What OP has to work with is that `.slice()` creates a new `Blob` that is stored in "memory". It is perhaps beyond the scope of this Question to delve into exactly where and how `Blob`s are stored at user filesystem, though have asked the Question [Where is Blob binary data stored?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38239361/), and eventually found the files. Germane in that multiple `.slice()` and `.readAsArraBuffer()` calls can be omitted.

Comment: oh snap, you're right about blob-internals, been a while, sorry about that! by vaporware I mean that `new Blob([]).close()` doesn't work in chrome or anywhere else i tried, at least not yet ;)

Comment: @dandavis _"I mean that `new Blob([]).close()` doesn't work in chrome or anywhere else i tried"_ What do you mean by "doesn't work"? Which version of chrome did you try at? 1) Open `chrome://blob-internals`; 2) at `console` or an `html` `document`, `var blob = new Blob([1,2,3])`; 3) reload `chrome://blob-internals` to view reference to `Blob`; 4) call `blob.close()`; 5) reload  `chrome://blob-internals`; 6) Note the changes to `Blob` reference listed at the page.

Comment: i mean that if i paste that into devtools i get `Uncaught TypeError: blob.close is not a function`

Comment: @dandavis Which version of chrome did you try at?

Comment: `Version 55.0.2883.87 m (64-bit)`, which it claims is up to date... Is close() a few weeks away? (yay)

Comment: @dandavis Interesting. Do not usually use chrome, here. The above procedure returns results described at chromium 52. Try launching with  each of and both of these flags set `--enable-experimental-web-platform-features`,  `--javascript-harmony `.

Comment: i already have those chrome-flag'd, is that the same? man, i can never even find chrome....

Comment: @dandavis _"i already have those chrome-flag'd"_ What do you mean? The instance of chrome which you tried at has those flags set? Open `chrome://version` review "Command Line", what is present between `--flag-switches-begin` and `--flag-switches-end` ? _"man, i can never even find chrome...."_?

Comment: @dandavis What is the executable line at desktop launcher for chrome?

Comment: ok, `\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --flag-switches-begin --no-pings --enable-devtools-experiments --javascript-harmony ... ` Must be the experimental web platform features, i sometimes turn that off to test prod ;)

Comment: @dandavis With the flag enabled, is the reference to the `Blob` data removed at `chrome://blob-internals` when the steps at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41440235/chrome-memory-issue-file-api-angularjs/41510379?noredirect=1#comment70356290_41510379 are followed?

Comment: i bet they would be, but i need to have to browser open for the next 73 mins at least, so i'll have to get back to you...

Comment: working remotely, in a meeting, shouldn't even be here but still waiting on the boss.