# Node.js: splitting stream content for n-parts

Tags: javascript, node.js, node.js-stream

I'm trying to understand node streams and their life-cycle. So, I want to split the content of a stream for n-parts. The code below is just to explain my intentions and to show that I already try something by myself. I omitted some details

I have a stream which just generates some data(just a sequence of numbers):

```
class Stream extends Readable {
  constructor() {
    super({objectMode: true, highWaterMark: 1})
    this.counter = 0
  }

  _read(size) {
    if(this.counter === 30) {
      this.push(null)
    } else {
      this.push(this.counter)
    }
    this.counter += 1
  }
}

const stream = new Stream()
stream.pause();
```

a function which tries to take n next chunks:

```
function take(stream, count) {
  const result = []
  return new Promise(function(resolve) {
    stream.once('readable', function() {
      var chunk;
      do {
        chunk = stream.read()
        if (_.isNull(chunk) || result.length > count) {
          stream.pause()
          break
        }
        result.push(chunk)
      } while(true)
      resolve(result)
    })
  })
}
```

and want to use it like this:

```
take(stream, 3)
  .then(res => {
    assert.deepEqual(res, [1, 2, 3])
    return take(stream, 3)
  })
  .then(res => {
    assert.deepEqual(res, [4, 5, 6])
  })
```

What is the idiomatic way to do that?

Answer (score 8):

Using `ReadableStream` you could use a single function to check if elements of current chunk of data is equal to expected result.

Create variables, `CHUNK` and `N`, where `CHUNK` is the number of elements to slice or splice from original array, `N` is the variable incremented by `CHUNK` at each `.enqueue()` call within `pull()` call.

```js
const [data, CHUNK, result] = [[1,2,3,4,5,6], 3, []];

let N = 0;

const stream = new ReadableStream({
  pull(controller) {
    if (N < data.length)
      // slice `N, N += CHUNK` elements from `data`
      controller.enqueue(data.slice(N, N += CHUNK))
    else
      // if `N` is equal to `data.length` call `.close()` on stream
      controller.close()
  }
});

const reader = stream.getReader();

const processData = ({value, done}) => {
  // if stream is closed return `result`; `reader.closed` returns a `Promise`
  if (done) return reader.closed.then(() => result);
  if (data.slice(N - CHUNK, N).every((n, index) => n === value[index])) {
    console.log(`N: ${N}, value: [${value}]`)
    result.push(...value);
    return reader.read().then(data => processData(data))
  }
}

const readComplete = res => console.log(`result: [${res}]`);

reader.read()
.then(processData)
.then(readComplete)
.catch(err => console.log(err));
```

Using chained `.then()`

```js
const [data, CHUNK, result] = [[1,2,3,4,5,6], 3, []];

let N = 0;

const stream = new ReadableStream({
  pull(controller) {
    if (N < data.length)
      // slice `N, N += CHUNK` elements from `data`
      controller.enqueue(data.slice(N, N += CHUNK))
    else
      // if `N` is equal to `data.length` call `.close()` on stream
      controller.close()
  }
});

const reader = stream.getReader();

const processData = ({value, done}) => {
  // if stream is closed return `result`; `reader.closed` returns a `Promise`
  if (done) return reader.closed.then(() => result);
  if (data.slice(N - CHUNK, N).every((n, index) => n === value[index])) {
    console.log(`N: ${N}, value: [${value}]`)
    result.push(...value);
    return reader.read().then(data => processData(data))
  }
}

const readComplete = res => console.log(`result: [${res}]`);

reader.read()
.then(({value, done}) => {
  if ([1,2,3].every((n, index) => n === value[index])) {
    console.log(`N: ${N}, value: [${value}]`)
    result.push(...value);
    return reader.read()
  }
})
.then(({value, done}) => {
  if ([4,5,6].every((n, index) => n === value[index])) {
    console.log(`N: ${N}, value: [${value}]`)
    result.push(...value);
    // return `result`; `reader.closed` returns a `Promise`
    return reader.closed.then(() => result);
  }
})
.then(readComplete)
.catch(err => console.log(err));
```

See also [Chrome memory issue - File API + AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41440235/chrome-memory-issue-file-api-angularjs/41510379#41510379)

Comment: can you give a link for some documentation about ReadableStream? the actual question is about Node.js streams which is probably something different

Comment: @kharandziuk See [Streams Standard](https://github.com/whatwg/streams), [web-streams-polyfill](https://github.com/creatorrr/web-streams-polyfill)

Comment: it's not the expected answer, but I'll probably give you the reward. At least I found something new in it

Comment: @kharandziuk Not certain if `nodejs` implements Streams Standard, though that is the specification. You can ask one of the maintainers of the standard or `nodejs` maintainers if the standard is implemented by `nodejs`.

Answer (score -1):

I think this is something that could help you out - https://github.com/substack/stream-handbook

It's an amazingly detailed handbook with sample code for various streaming scenarios and I'm using the same as a reference for my own project and have found it useful so far! It has sample code in [/examples](https://github.com/substack/stream-handbook/tree/master/example) as well

Comment: I didn't find the answer here

Comment: It references the npm package called split, that could be applied in your case - 
https://www.npmjs.com/package/split
https://www.npmjs.com/package/split2