# Where does Chromium store Javascript temp data

Tags: javascript, chromium

Chromium runs a web Javascript application from a site.
The JS code is obfuscated and is a lot of code.
The app loads some data to display.
I do not see the data stored on the file system (I run a 'find' to see if any files have been modifed right after loading the app and no files are modified).
The data IS stored somewhere locally because when internet is unplugged whatever loaded data is still showing.
Where is the data stored?? How do I find it and extract it? Is it in memory only? How would I go about scraping the data?

EDIT: [Where is Blob binary data stored?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38239361/where-is-blob-binary-data-stored) answers my question partially - the data is in RAM. The question that remains is how to narrow down where in RAM. Is it possible to scan recently changed RAM for some features that we know of the data?

Comment: probably you mean localStorage / Cookies?

Comment: While on the site, open dev tools and do type `localStorage` into the console. This will return whats saved in local storage there. Fair chance that's where it will be.

Comment: It looks like localStorage only saves properties of the app window, not the actual data

Comment: RAM access depends on your OS.

Answer (score 0):

**For Chrome on Windows 11**

On Windows, Chrome stores under your user profile folder e.g. `C:\Users\*******\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Profile 1`.

The `AppData` folder is usually hidden and not visible in Windows Explorer by default.

I can see there is a file called `Cookies` which appears to be a SQLite database.

There are other folders for `Local Storage`, `Session Storage` and `IndexedDB`.

**EDIT:** ***Just noticed that you've asked specifically about Chromium - not sure if any of this is relevant.***